# set ip addres in my guest OS with proxmox use cli

Tags: cloud-init, proxmox

I use guest OS ubuntu 22, proxmox 7.0-8.
using the command `qm set 302  --ipconfig0 ip=10.10.10.1/28` i expect that addres to change, but it doesn't happen. VM use ip from template vm. In GUI interface in settings VM, in the Cloud-init block ip was set.

I tried change cloud init settings in guest VM, but I don't really understand what needs to be changed.